# ¿Cómo minificar y encriptar mis archivos JS al ejecutar npm run build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

Tengo una aplicación en VueJS, pero a esta tambien le cree algunos scripts que son generales y quedaron en la carpeta public, cuando hago el comando `npm run build` para crear el publicado de mi app y pasarla a producción, mis archivos JS que hice, están tal cual, creí que se minificarian automáticamente o similar.

Quisiera saber cómo poder minificar los archivos .js (y .css si se puede) y si hay alguna forma de "*encriptar*" el código dentro para que no sea visto tan fácilmente como ahora que al entrar a la consola ya veo tal cual el código.

Este es mi `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "sjcl": "^1.0.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-backtotop": "^1.6.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^2.1.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.10.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "sass": "^1.17.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que instalar el plugin UglifyJS de webpack y modificar el archivo *webpack.config.js* así:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "bundle": "./entry.js",
        "bundle.min": "./entry.js",
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        path: "./dist",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.min\.js$/,
            minimize: true
        }),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
            hashFunction: 'sha256',
            hashDigest: 'hex',
            hashDigestLength: 20
        })
    ]
};
```

Con esa configuración obtendrás dos versiones de tu script uno en formato de producción `entry.min.js` y otro en formato de desarrollo `entry.js`.

También puedes usar `HashedModuledsPlugin` para encriptar los nombres de la funciones en formato **sha256**

Comment: No tengo ningun archivo llamado `webpack.config.js`, solo tengo uno llamado `package.json` y otro llamado `package-lock.json`, lo hago en ese mismo?

Comment: @FabianMontoya usas sólo NPM? O webpack también? Si no usas webpack puedes instalarlo con este comando ```npm i -g webpack``` para que así puedes hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Solo uso NPM, no veo la necesidad del uso de webpack, o para qué me serviría instalar el webpack tambien?, soy nuevo en el tema de NPM y webpack

Comment: @FabianMontoya webpack facilita el empaquetamiento de scripts js, css, svg y html. Así como el caso tuyo que necesitas minificar los archivos js

Comment: @FabianMontoya te dejo este vídeo de youtube donde te explica lo básico de webpack https://youtu.be/vF2emKbaP4M

Comment: Entendí mas o menos todo el funcionamiento, pero aún no logro integrarlo a mi proyecto jaja

Comment: @FabianMontoya para integrarlo a tu proyecto solo usa el comando ```npm install --save-dev webpack``` desde cmd en la carpeta o directorio de tu preoyecto, automáticamente se añadirán las dependencias al archivo ```package.json```, en el campo "devDependicies" después de eso modifica el archivo ```webpack.config.js``` y ejecuta el comando ```npm run build```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97735/discussion-between-rimuru-tempest-and-fabian-montoya).